# Round off periods to nearest minutes using lubridate

Tags: r, datetime, rounding, lubridate

I was  wondering if we can round off `period` to nearest minutes using `lubridate`. For ex - the value of `time_diff` is "2H 13M 9S". How can I get round off `time_diff` to nearest minute to get "2H 13M" (remove seconds)

```
library(lubridate)

time_1 <- ymd_hms("2021-01-01 12:12:36")
time_2 <- ymd_hms("2021-01-01 14:25:45")

time_diff <- seconds_to_period(difftime(time_2, time_1, units = 'sec'))
```

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17108515/680068

Answer (score 3):

Convert to integer, remove seconds, then convert to period:

```
x <- as.integer(difftime(time_2, time_1, units = "sec"))
seconds_to_period(x - (x %% 60))
# [1] "2H 13M 0S"
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to remove the second component i.e. "2H 13M"

Answer (score 1):

We can convert to `POSIXct` and then use `round_date`

```
library(lubridate)
time_diff1 <- sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', time_diff@hour,
     time_diff@minute, second(time_diff))
 format(round_date(as.POSIXct(time_diff1, format = '%H:%M:%S'),
       unit = "minute"), '%H:%M')
[1] "02:13"
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to obtain in this format -  "2H 13M", but not as character, I would like to further add/subtract it